# Palidrome program is not workig

Tags: c

i am trying to make a palindrome program using simple logic but unfortunate I can't get the output being typed in `Printf( "This is palindrome")`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{   
    int a,b,c,d,e,f;

    printf("enter the 5 digit of palindrome");

    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f);

    if(a==f &&  b==e && c==d)
    {
        printf("Its a Palindrome");
    }
    else if( a!=f || b!=e || c!=d){

        printf("its a palindrome");

    }

getchar();

    return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you read a string, rather than trying to read individual digits as numbers.

Comment: There are two texts saying "Its a palindrome", and OP seeks for "This is a palindrome". Not sure what is expected. Also from what I remember by mister De Morgan, the second `if` is reduntant.

Comment: Your both the printf statements are same.. Pls check

Comment: Vote to close for careless typos.

Comment: your program only works for 6 digit palindromes, you should improve it to handle more digits, what if someone input 3digits? maybe 10digits? shuold keep you busy, scanf in not the solution for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e,&f);
```

You should have another `%d` there. Otherwise `f` contains a garbage value and it'll be never equals `a`.

I recommend you to reconsider your code and write something more general, like reading a string instead of individual `int`s.

Comment: Yeah Man; it approximately worked.. but its doing the wrong waylike" if i type 55555 then its printed as "it is not a palidrome which is conflicting my logic.

Comment: @user3285610 Because you entered 5 `int`s only. Check your condition.

Comment: change your first printf statement to 
printf("enter the 6 digit of palindrome");

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code:

- you call scanf() with 5 `%d`, but pass 6 parameters (you're missing a `%d`)
- your condition in the else branch is superfluous; you already know that at least one of the pairs (a,f), (b,e), (c,d) doesn't contain two equal values
- in your else branch, you have `printf("its a palindrome")`, whereas it clearly *is not* a palindrome

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a,b,c,d,e;

    printf("enter the 5 digit of palindrome :");
    scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);

    if(a==e && b==d)
        printf("it's a palindrome");
    else
        printf("it's not a palindrome");

    getchar();

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if( a!=f || b!=e || c!=d){
    printf("its a palindrome");
}
```

If the first and the last digit do not equal then it **is not** a palindrome.